# Salesforce Tooling API - insufficient access rights

Tags: api, salesforce

I am attempting to create a trigger through the Tooling API. This is being executed within Salesforce and being performed on the same Salesforce org. This is being done in a dev org and the running user is an administrator.

When I create the `MetadataContainer` it works as expected.  When I create the `ApexTriggerMember` I am presented with the following error:

```
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY
```

Here is some debugging of the process along the way:

```
The JSON that is sent to create the MetadataContainer
{"Name":"Container 2013-03-08 17:28:06"}
```

The URL it's being sent to

```
https://na11.salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/tooling/sobjects/MetadataContainer/
```

The response:

```
{"id":"1dcG0000000PAwZIAW","success":true,"errors":[]}
```

The JSON that is sent to create the ApexTriggerMember

```
{"MetadataContainerId":"1dcG0000000PAwZIAW","Body":"trigger TestTrg1 on Account (after insert, after update, before insert, before update) {\n\n}"}
```

The URL it's being sent to:

```
https://na11.salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTriggerMember/
```

The response:

```
[{"fields":[],"message":"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id","errorCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY"}]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the same thing but via the SOAP version of the Tooling API.

It worked fine if I specified the ApexTriggerMember.ContentEntityId as an existing Trigger Id (key prefix 01q). Of course, this is updating an existing trigger rather than creating a new trigger.

If I didn't set the ContentEntityId I get exactly the same error you do. "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" (StatusCode.INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY)

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/index.htm) says (my emphasis):

> **ContentEntityId**
>   Type: reference
>   Properties: Create, Filter, Group, Sort
>   Description:
>   A reference to an Apex trigger.
>   There can be only one ContentEntityId per ApexTriggerMember,
>   otherwise, an error is reported.
>   **This field is required.**

So the field is required, but we don't have an Id to assign to it yet...

Note, I've asked a similar question on the dedicated Salesforce StackExchange - [How do I use the Tooling API to create a new Apex Trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/how-do-i-use-the-tooling-api-to-create-a-new-apex-trigger)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Through testing I believe the tooling API is not intended for create.  If that is wrong, I hope someone can provide more details.  At this point we are going to migrate all attention toward to the metadata API to get this resolved.  Thank you again for all of your help.